# xcode 6 custom tab bar not showing images until they are selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tabs

I have several apps that I wrote a couple of years ago that are on the store and all fine, working, approved, etc.

I have now opened them up in Xcode 6 to do some updates to them, and the custom tab bar that I wrote and was working fine in Xcode 4 now displays very odd behaviour.

The bar shows up blank on first load, but when each tab is touched/selected, then the image loads. Once all tabs have been selected once, then the bar is fully working and all images are showing up as expected - but on first load the tab bar shows blank (except for the first tab, because it is selected).

[image]

The code hasn't changed since it previously worked, all images are there and loaded fine, because once a tab is selected then they show up fine. It is only on first load that the images don't appear, until that tab is touched and selected.

My code for this custom tab bar is as follows, which all worked fine previously, and works fine in the apps on the store now:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
CGRect tabbarTopFrame = CGRectMake(0,(screenSize.height - 59),320,10);
UIImageView *tabbarTop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:tabbarTopFrame];
tabbarTop.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_top.png"];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:tabbarTop];

UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_introduction_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_introduction_default.png"];
UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_nests_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_nests_default.png"];
UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_home_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_home_default.png"];
UIImage *selectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_dogowners_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_dogowners_default.png"];
UIImage *selectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_spotted_active.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_spotted_default.png"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

item0.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item2.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item3.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
item4.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
[item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage4 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage4];
```

What has changed since Xcode 4 regarding the above code, or is there any issues with the above code that would cause the images not to load until after they have been selected?

Xcode shows no errors or warnings with the code as shown.

This is causing me no end of grief, and I just cant understand this behaviour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
```

The function is deprecated first in iOS7.

The alternative:

```
[item0 setImage:[unselectedImage0 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

    [item0 setSelectedImage:[selectedImage0 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Comment: Genius! This fixes it. Thanks - I owe you a beer :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the *unselectedimages* are not missing in the folder. Try to remove and reconnect this images again and make sure to add them to target.